# How to find files with specific extensions, while excluding some names in the current directory only?

Tags: find, wildcards, aix, non-gnu

I want to **find** some files, in a non GNU environment

- in the current directory only
- with extension ***.ext1** and ***.ext2**,
- but not **name1.*** or **name2.***

The following command works, but may be not efficient, because the shell expands `./*` and **find** can get a huge list of files and directories.

```
find ./* -prune \( -name '*ext1' -o -name '*ext2' \) -a ! \( -name 'name1*' -o -name 'name2*' \)
```

**Update:**

I'm working on AIX, there is no **-maxdepth** option.

Comment: Are you working in ksh?

Comment: No, in bash. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `find`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune \
    \( -name '*.ext1' -o -name '*.ext2' \) \
  ! \( -name 'name1.*' -o -name 'name2.*' \)
```

Using `-prune` is the standard equivalent of GNU's `-maxdepth`. Here it tells `find` not to descend in any directory except `.`.

the `! -name .` makes it also exclude `.` from the selection, so `! -name . -prune` is the standard equivalent of GNU's `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`. For GNU's `-mindepth 1`, you'd write `find . \( -name . -o -prune \)`.

With `zsh`, you can also make it:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- *.(ext1|ext2)~(name1|name2).*(ND)
```

`~` being the and-not operator, and `(D)` to include dot-files.

Comment: Thank you, this is the fastest solution indeed :) `find . ! -name . -prune` is the point!

Answer (score 2):

In your current directory you can use `ls` with `grep` (assuming your file names don't contain newline characters):

```
ls -a | grep -E '\.ext(1|2)$' | grep -vE '^name(1|2)\.'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! It runs much faster as my solution with globbing. 
I've not enough reputation to vote it up :(

Answer (score 0):

"In the current directory only" you don't need to `find` files, you can simply list them (with the usual caveats about the possibility of encoutering bizarre file names, containing interesting characters):

```
ls -d *.ext1 *.ext2 2>/dev/null | grep -v '^\(name1\|name2\)\.'
```

Comment: Consider a huge directory with many files and folders... I would avoid shell globbing.

Comment: Why is shell globbing less eficient that `find`? `find` has no special method of looking at file names.

Comment: Ok, but the "transport" of a huge list of parameters between the shell and `find` takes time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have bash available, you can use its [extended pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
shopt -s extglob
files=( !(name1|name2).@(ext1|ext2) )
```

This says: all the files in the current directory that do *not* start with "name1" or "name2", followed by a period, followed by *either* "ext1" or "ext2".

For a sample run:

```
$ touch name1.ext1 name1.ext2 name2.ext1 name2.ext2 name3.ext1 name3.ext2 name3.ext3
$ files=( !(name1|name2).@(ext1|ext2) )
$ declare -p files
declare -a files='([0]="name3.ext1" [1]="name3.ext2")'
```

Note that if you have a simple filename like "name3.ext2", you have to choose where to put the period for the pattern matching -- either in "name3." *or* in ".ext2"; if you have longer filenames, such as "name3.intermediate.ext2", then you could use dots and a glob in the middle:

```
$ files=( !(name1|name2).*.@(ext1|ext2) )
```